# Could not cast value of type 'Work.Login' (0x10c5edd20) to 'Work.DataBaseConn'

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

I have a problem with my second viewController when trying to send data with segue. The code of Login is:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let secondView = segue.destination as! DataBaseConn
        secondView.user=TextUsername.text!
        secondView.pass=Pass.text!
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "sendData", sender: self)


    }
```

I get the error at this line:

```
  let secondView = segue.destination as! DataBaseConn
```

Both views have the custom class set.

Comment: What is `DataBaseConn`? `UIViewController` or `UIView`

Comment: I know that it is UIViewController but I don't know how to check that.

Comment: replace the line with `guard let secondView = segue.destination as? DataBaseConn else { return }`

Comment: it worked. now I have no error. Thank you!

Comment: but now.. the segue is not working. My "user" and "pass" don't have the data anymore

Comment: It’s not anymore if it didn’t work in the first place again what is DataBaseConn and what is the class name of the next view controller

Comment: DataBaseConn is declared like this : class DataBaseConn: UIViewController and it's a Cocoa Touch file.

Comment: The views are : Login->Alege->DataBaseConn. Even if I send the data from Login to Alege and than I push it from Alege to DataBaseConn I have the same error. I get the error only when I press the back button from the Alege view controller